# How do I setup an XMPP server for Facebook that returns JSON?

Tags: json, facebook, xmpp, chat

In a nutshell, here is what I want to do:

1. Query a URL like www.mysite.com/?action=GetOnlineList&access_token=[Facebook Token]
2. Have that URL then return a list of all the user's Facebook friends online in JSON

I could then also do some other actions like "SendMessage" and "GetMessages" as well.

I've been reading up on this for a while and so far I've gathered that I will need XMPP/Jabber to do this, but I don't know exactly where to start.

Would creating an OpenFire server allow me to do this?  I'm not familiar with XMPP at all, so I don't know how I'd be able to spit out JSON data from the server.  Would I be able to setup queries like that on an OpenFire server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to run a full XMPP server like Openfire, you want to connect to Facebook as a client (the same way users do).

There are two components you need; first you want some code in the browser to request the info from Facebook's XMPP server. However you can't connect directly to Facebook's XMPP direct from the browser (they only support XMPP over standard sockets), so you will also need something else: some kind of proxy on your server for your code to connect through.

There are some ready-made solutions for this, you can use [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/) with a [BOSH connection manager](http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/technology-overview/bosh/#impl-cm) running on your server. This allows you to log into the user's Facebook chat and fetch the info you need using XMPP. Make sure you use a standalone BOSH proxy, many XMPP servers (like Openfire, Prosody, ejabberd) have their own BOSH interfaces, but these won't allow you to connect to Facebook.

Since you say you require JSON, there are a couple of alternatives you might prefer to try, such as [xmpp-ftw](https://xmpp-ftw.jit.su/) or [stanza.io](http://stanza.io). Both of these let you deal with the XMPP server via JSON only, and xmpp-ftw is especially appropriate because it even includes the proxy part that you need (using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)). It has well documented simple commands, the only thing you will need to learn are some XMPP basics, such as terminology (the "roster" is your contact list, and "presence" is someone's status, etc.).

Comment: Thank you Matt, this should certainly be enough to get me started. I appreciate the in-depth response!